# What is the equivalent of F no capo with 3rd fret capo

Tags: guitar

On standard guitar, F is 133211 when no capo.

If I put a capo on the 3rd fret, what note should play to have similar  sound

Comment: For future reference, the chart in this answer on Stack Exchange Music will help you identify capo chord to open chord equivalents for all common keys and major chords (https://music.stackexchange.com/a/30935/16897)

Comment: I hope you meant **NOTES** as one note makes the question meaningless.

Comment: @Tim Actually, since both the note and major chord are written exactly the same way, "F", beginners might not even know they're playing chords. I'm playing "F"! I just had a beginner guitarist ask about this after I showed C major and C minor chords on the piano, and what the "formula" for major and minor chords is. He asked, "when the guitar plays C, does the pianist play C major or C minor?"  It took me some time to realize he doesn't know he's playing chords, not single notes. All the lead sheets and youtube and apps and everything just show "C" and it doesn't say major or minor anywhere!

Answer (score 6):

That would be x00232

That's the common D chord position, and if you bring it up 3 semitones, it becomes an F.